# Create external table from csv file in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to create an external table in AWS Athena from a csv file that is stored in my S3.

The csv file looks as follows. As you can see, the data is **not** enclosed in quotation marks (`"`) and is delimited by commas (`,`).

```
ID,PERSON_ID,DATECOL,GMAT
612766604,54723367,2020-01-15,637
615921503,158634997,2020-01-25,607
610656030,90359154,2020-01-07,670
```

I tried the following code to create a table:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table
    (
        ID string,
        PERSON_ID int,
        DATE_COL date,
        GMAT int
    )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://my_bucket/som_bucket/dat/'
TBLPROPERTIES
    (
        'skip.header.line.count'='1'
    )
;
```

I tried to preview the table with the following code:

```sql
select
    *
from
    my_table
limit 10
```

Which raises this error:

> HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '2020-01-15' for field 2: For input string: "2020-01-15"

My question is: Am I passing the correct serde? And if so, how can I format the date column (`DATE_COL`) such that it reads and displays days in YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: You have the amazon-redshift tag.  This seems to be only a question about Athena?

Comment: My bad. I removed it. I keep forgetting that Athena and Redshift are not the same product.

Comment: Don't let AWS hear you say that :-)

Comment: As per this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html you need to declare them as int. Can you try changing the data type to int and rerun your query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I replaced `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'` with
`FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` and enclosed the column names with "`". The following code creates the table correctly:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table
    (
        `ID` string,
        `PERSON_ID` int,
        `DATE_COL` date,
        `GMAT` int
    )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://my_bucket/som_bucket/dat/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
;
```

I do not understand the concept of a `serde`, but I suppose I did not need one to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html), a column with type DATE must have a values representing the number of days since January 1, 1970. For example, the date on row 1 after your header should have a value of 18276. When the table is queried the date will then be rendered as 2020-01-15.